# vagrant init すると "already exists" と言われ、起動の仕方がわからない

Tags: vagrant

独学で初めてのProgrammingなので、かなり初歩的な質問ですがご協力ください。
私はMacOSX Yosemite でPythonをProgrammingするため、ローカル開発環境を構築、準備をしていたのですが以下のようになってしまい、エラーなのか上手くいきません。(TerminalでVagrant実行中に)　
ネットで調べたもののどうすれば良いのか、よくわかりませんでした。
初心者でもわかる丁寧なご教示をお願いできればありがたいです。
補足:Vagrant　バージョン1.8.1

```
$ cd
$ mkdir MyVagrant
mkdir: MyVagrant: File exists
$ cd MyVagrant
$ mkdir mycentos
mkdir: mycentos: File exists
$ cd mycentos
$ vagrant init bento/centos-6.7
`Vagrantfile` already exists in this directory. Remove it before
running `vagrant init`.
$ vi Vagrantfile
```

ここでEnterを押すと長くて意味のわからない文字が出てきました。

Answer (score 2):

Vagrantを実行(起動)するには`vagrant up`というコマンドを使います。

エラー文に関しては、`vagrant init`の実行によってVagrantfileというファイルが作成されますが、Vagrantfileが既に作成されているということはおそらく`vagrant init`も既に実行されているということです。

最後に実行された`vi Vagrantfile`は[vi](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi)というテキストエディタを起動してVagrantfileの内容を表示します。

Comment: なんとなく理解できました！
しかし実は最初に古い情報を参考にしてしまい、
`$ vagrant init bento/centos-6.7`　を
`$ vagrant init chef/centos-6.5`　と打ってしまいました。
そして`vagrant up`コマンドを入力したら、今度は

`The box 'chef/centos-6.5' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/chef/centos-6.5"]
Error: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found `

と出てきてしまいました。
全て削除してやり直しする事はできますか？

Comment: `vagrant box remove chef/centos-6.5`で現在のboxを削除し、`vagrant box add bento/centos-6.7`で6.7のboxを追加してみてください。

Comment: 解決できました！
が、すぐにまた問題が発生してしまいました。
`vagrant up`で起動してる最中に落ちて再起動してしまうのです。
vagrant ver1.8.1 です。
OSは OSX Yosemite ver 10.10.3 です。
メモリも十分あると思います。
もしくは、他のアプリを起動しながらだとダメなのでしょうか？
(例：Safari、メモ など)

Comment: 再起動する直前にエラー文ありませんか？

Comment: エラー文も無しですね。
`vagrant up`で起動して、ロードしてる文みたいなのがいっぱい出てきてる途中で一瞬だけ止まって、画面が暗くなって再起動します。
再起動をする際、「コンピュータに何らかの問題が発生したので再起動します。」
といった感じの文が発生します。

Comment: あと、どうやら自分はvagrantを初期化して CentOSを立ち上げようとしていたみたいですね。
なので、CentOSを立ち上げようとして落ちてしまったようです。
ちなみに、ドットインストールを参考にしています。